# What analyses do I use?

Tags: multiple-regression, ancova, multilevel-analysis

If I have two categorical IVs and one continuous IV and I want to see if the two categorical IVs predict a continuous DV over and above the effect of the continuous IV, what analysis should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial regression plots.

If the plot of residuals of the following regressions show a pattern, then yes, the categorical IVs are indeed adding further value.

1. Regress Y on the categorical IVs
2. Regress the categorical IVs against the continuous IVs

Use the residual plots of 1 vs 2 to see if the categorical IVs are adding any additional value.